# Is there a better way to create a dynamic rails path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, wicked-gem

Is there a better way to do this in Rails using the wicked gem?

```
def finish_wizard_path
  public_send("#{controller_name}_path", current_user.try(controller_name.intern).id)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using `url_for` method

```
url_for(controller: controller_name, action: :new, id: current_user.id)
```